# Webhook Listener for Eventbrite

Tags: listener, aws-lambda, webhooks, eventbrite

I've been searching far and wide for samples of Webhook Listeners for Eventbrite. My goal is to implement it into amazon api gateway and lambda. I've seen many tutorials configuring the gateway, but no sample code for eventbrite.

Does anyone have anything for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for something similar, and I've stumbled in this article, which I think might be a good starting point: https://developers.exlibrisgroup.com/blog/Hosting-a-Webhook-Listener-in-AWS

It doesn't cover how to create an Eventbrite webhook listener specifically, but it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you, but tried that route already without success. Hopefully someone will have specific guidance for eventbrite.

Comment: I'm probably going to work on this myself shortly, so I will probably post my solution here once I figure it out.

Comment: Nice! I'll keep an eye out for it.

Answer (score 0):

I actually made a PHP listener last year that took the attendee.updated event and performed a lookup to get the updated attendee info. I used an API framework, so I'll just give you the most important bits you might be able to transpose for use with Lambda:

```
//Assuming $body is the webhook payload
$url = $body['api_url'];
$arr = explode('/',rtrim(substr($url,strpos($url,'events/')),'/'));
for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i+=2) {
    $parts[$arr[$i]] = $arr[$i+1];
}
```

Using [eventbrite/eventbrite-sdk-php](https://github.com/eventbrite/eventbrite-sdk-php) I created a wrapper class:

```
class Eventbrite {

    const OAUTH_TOKEN = '(TOKEN)';

    function __construct() {
        $this->Client = new \HttpClient(self::OAUTH_TOKEN);
    }

    public function get_attendee($event = '(DEFAULT EVENT ID)',$id) {
        $path = "/events/".$event."/attendees/".$id."/";
        return $this->Client->get($path);
        //return array($path);
    }
    public function get_order($order) {
        $path = "/orders/".$order;
        return $this->Client->get($path);
    }
}
```

And then with that `$parts` array:

```
$Eventbrite = new Eventbrite();
$attendee = $Eventbrite->get_attendee($parts['events'],$parts['attendees']);
```

You then have all the attendee's registration information, status, etc., in the `$attendee` array, e.g. `$attendee['profile']['first_name']`.